# How do I add more account fields for user registration?

Tags: users, form

I'm using the default form found in the Craft CMS docs, however I'd like to create more fields other than username, password and email. How would I add more custom fields to capture user data like address, phone number etc?

Answer (score 3):

Create the input fields as you would any other, maybe add them to a 'users' group, then you can go to:

```
/admin/settings/users/fields
```

and add them via the layout designer, you should then see them appear when viewing a user in the admin area, under the profile tab I believe :)