# Using Form to update User Profile and submit form

Tags: users, form, user-profile

Checking the best way to achieve this or if it can be done without a plugin.
I need to allow people to register and create user accounts on my site with various profile information.

Then I will have a form on the site available to users to submit which saves it in the backend and alerts by email. (A&M forms looks like it has this functionality). When a user logs in this form should be prepopulated with data from their user profile.

When the form is submitted - can it update their user profile also?

It is basically a form for users to order repeat prescriptions - so I'm thinking user profile to save the standard date then use that to prepopulate the a&m form. Is what I'm suggesting the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that's totally do-able. Check out [this article](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) to see how to create a registration form.

Then check out [this article](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-profile-form) to see how to create the update profile form.

The thing to note is that any custom fields like `address` or `city` need to be pre-pended with `fields`.

So, let's say you want the user to enter their city. On your front-end form the markup looks like this:

```
<h3><label for="city">City</label></h3>
<input id="city" type="text" name="fields[city]"
{%- if currentUser is defined %} value="{{ currentUser.city }}"{% endif %}>
    {% if currentUser is defined %}
        {{ errorList(currentUser.getErrors('city')) }}
    {% endif %}
```

... and so on.

Make sure that your field handle(s) in the CP align with what you call them on your front-end form.

[Here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/351/how-can-i-determine-if-a-user-is-logged-in-and-who-that-user-is) is how you can check for the current user.

[Here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4332/how-to-add-custom-user-fields-to-the-front-end-registration-page) is another great example of how to populate custom fields in your profile/registration form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I have created users account forms etc all before - all fairly straight forward;
Then when a user is logged in to Order a repeat prescription - that User Profile Data would auto-complete the Order Form - I was thinking of using the a&m forms plugin for that - so each Order is stored in the CMS and an email sent. I was wondering when that order form is submitted could that also update their user profile if there was any differences in it?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way. My guess is that you would need to create some sort of plugin that listens to the order form submit, then updates the user profile within craft.